# jQuery selector with variable...how to piece it together?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

I am trying to loop through each list item in a given list. I will have several unordered lists on the same page, so I need to specify which list by its ID. I'm not sure however, how to use a jQuery selector to first find the correct ul, then iterate through the list items.

Here is my attempt:

```
<ul id="list-102">
    <li id="item-1:3.3.0096_43" class="show">1</li>
    <li id="item-1:3.3.0097_9" class="show">2</li>
    <li id="item-1:3.3.0098_34" class="show">3</li>
    <li id="item-1:3.3.0099_35" class="show">4</li>
</ul>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
    var num = 102
    var listToSearch = "list-" + num;

            //create an empty array
            var allItems = [];

    $('#' + listToSearch > 'li').each(function(i) {
                var itemID= ($( this ).attr('id'));
                var idLength = itemID.length;
                var beginHere = itemID.indexOf('_');
                var callNum = itemID.substr(beginHere + 1, idLength );
                allItems.push(callNum);
            });
    alert(allItems);        
</script>
```

I'm open to any and all suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: `'#' + listToSearch + '> li'`

Comment: @j08691 Sorry, I was obfuscating my code a little before posting and missed that one.

Comment: Well between that typo and the one that Karl-AndréGagnon pointed out, your code works fine. You just made sloppy typos.

Comment: @j08691 You are correct, but thanks for pointing it out. We all learn at different paces. Thanks for your constructive criticism on this one and helping me become a better coder.

Comment: That's just a dick move to give a -1 and not even mention as to why.  Giving you +1 to counter that -1.  Seriously people? -1 for someone asking a question for god's sake?

Comment: Thanks for the good karma @Lukas. You've got your head on straight. People like that are just clearly miserable and only want the same for others. Good lookin out. Good things are coming your way.